# Merge multiple pandas dataframe along with np.where to process values

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, `df1`:

```
id  level  val
1   l1     0.2
1   l2     0.1
```

and another dataframe which contains type for `l1` level, `df2`:

```
id  type
1   A
```

Similarly, `df3` which contains type for `l2` level as well as new ids:

```
id  new_id  type
1   19      A
1   19      B
1   20      A
1   20      B
```

Now I want type for `l1` level from `df2`. And for `l2` level from `df3`, while also resetting ids and level. This is what I am doing:

```
df2['level'] = 'l1'
df3['level'] = 'l2'
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['id','level'])
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df3, how='outer', on=['id','level'], suffixes=["_", ""])
df1['id'] = np.where(df1['new_id'].isnull(), df1['id'], df1['new_id'])
df1['type'] = np.where(df1['type'].isnull(), df1['type_'], df1['type'])
df1['level'] = np.where(df1['level']=='l2', 'l3', df1['level'])
df1 = df1.drop('new_id', 1)
df1 = df1.drop('type_', 1)
```

Which finally gives me, `df1`:

```
id  level  val  type
1   l1     0.2  A
19  l3     0.1  A
19  l3     0.1  B
20  l3     0.1  A
20  l3     0.1  B
```

Since `df1` is a large dataframe, I want to avoid using `np.where` thrice, i.e., I am looking for a faster approach to get this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## keyword arguments

I had to check the documentation to find out what the `1` means in `df1.drop('new_id', 1)`. More clear would be `df1.drop('new_id', axis=1)`, or even better: `df1.drop(columns=["type_", "new_id"])`

## Don't overwrite raw data

You add columns and values to `df1`, which makes finding problems harder.

With a bit of reshuffling, and using `df.join` instead of `pd.merge`, you can make your intent a bit more clear

```
df6= df1.join(
    df2.assign(level="l1").set_index(["id", "level"]),
    how="outer",
    on=["id", "level"],
).join(
    df3.assign(level="l2").set_index(["id", "level"]),
    how="outer",
    on=["id", "level"],
    lsuffix="_",
)
```

## np.where

If you're looking for null, you can use `fillna` or [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html). To replace `'l2'` with `'l3'`, you can use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html).

```
df7 = df6.assign(
    id=df6["new_id"].fillna(df6["id"]).astype(int),
    type=df6["type_"].fillna(df6["type"]),
    level=df6["level"].replace("l2", "l3")
).drop(columns=["type_", "new_id"])
```

I don't know whether this approach will be faster, but to me, what happens here is a lot more clear.